# How to query the filter result in the following scenario in MYSQL/ SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I am working on a function that similar to Facebook comment / forum post.

The table structure is like this:

```
Post
========    
id
txtMsg
createDate
updateDate
isShow
userID
postID

User
=======
id
name
```

So , this table already represent the post and comment. That means, if it is a post , the postID will be null , and if this is reply, it has the parent postID.

My goal is

1. **get the user 's comment/ post as well as their friend's post order by create day (Desc)**.
2. There is a field call **isShow**, which mean , for any post that isShow is 0 , then all the post and the comment should not include in the result set.
3. Join the user table to get user name

I work on codeigniter project but that does not matter , I can convert the syntax SQL query. You are highly appreciate for provide any help.

In my expected outcome I can generate a output like this in my interface

```
    Comment-er name (comment date)
    comment message

    1st Reply-er name (1st reply date)
    1st reply message

    2nd Reply-er name (2nd reply date)
    2nd reply message

.....
```

Attempted code like this but need some adjustment , where $facebookIDList contains the userID and user's friends ID already

```
$this->db->select('c.id as id, u.name as username, c.txtMsg as txtMsg, c.createDate as createDate, c.updateDate as updateDate, c.imageURL as imageURL, c.postID as postID, c.isShow as isShow');
$this->db->from('comment as c, user as u');
$this->db->where('u.id = c.userID');
$this->db->where('c.isShow = 1');
$this->db->where_in('c.userID', $facebookIDList);
$this->db->order_by('c.createDate', 'Desc');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please clarify one thing. You said **"So , this table already represent the post and comment. That means, if it is a post , the postID will be null , and if this is reply, it has the parent postID."**
If postID is null for any new post then how you are putting parent postID in reply??

Comment: Thanks for reply. For a Post, e.g. ID : 5, POSTID : NULL, For a reply of it ,e.g. ID : 6 , POSTID:5 .

Comment: i think you should use different tables for post and comments/reply. both will connect through the userID and post ID. new post ID will be replyID which in your case postID. you can display the data according to that.